# JavaScript вызов функции в ответ на изменение локального файла

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли в js вызывать функцию только тогда, когда конкретный локальный файл был изменен?

Comment: this is russian version of stack oveflow, if u want this community to help you ask your question on russin, or go to stack overflow on eng, luck

Answer (score 4):

В браузере - нельзя, JavaScript в браузере не имеет доступа к файловой системе (API браузера нам в данном случае не поможет).

Если говорить о Node.JS, то в данном случае можно использовать [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener)

```
const fs = require('fs');

const file = '/var/log/example';

fs.watch(file, (event, filename) => {
    console.log(`${file} is changed`);
});
```

или [fs.watchFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener)

```
const fs = require('fs');

const file = '/var/log/example';

fs.watchFile(file, (curr, prev) => {
    console.log(`${file} is changed`);
});
```

Спасибо [@nörbörnën](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2659/n%C3%B6rb%C3%B6rn%C3%ABn) за дополнение к ответу

Comment: я бы предложил заменить `fs.watch` на `fs.watchFile` и, кроме этого, заменить ссылку на документацию к 7мой версии ноды на [актуальную](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) документацию

Comment: @nörbörnën спасибо за исправление, я обновил ссылки. В ответе я оставил оба варианта, т.к. в документации к `fs.watchFile` написано: `Using fs.watch() is more efficient than fs.watchFile and fs.unwatchFile. fs.watch should be used instead of fs.watchFile and fs.unwatchFile when possible.`.
Как я понял, `fs.watch` использует нативные функции OS, из-за этого он более эффективен, но может работать не на всех платформах, а `fs.watchFile` работает через `uv_fs_stat()`, который вызывает периодически, из-за чего работает медленнее, но на всех платформах.